# JavaFX: Can a TreeView's "selector bar" be adjusted to fit content?

Tags: java, css, javafx, treeview

By "selector bar", I am referring to the selected tree-cell from when you click on a node of the TreeView. I'm using javafx8.

[image]

When an object in a TreeView is selected, the selector bar stretches to edges of whatever pane contains the aforementioned TreeView, like in the image above. What I want to achieve can be seen below.

[image]

I figured a reasonable way to achieve this would be to write a couple of css blocks. First, one that makes the current selector bar not visible, like below,

```
.tree-cell:selected
{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

in combination with a css block to make whatever node contains the icon and label some background color. I can't find a resource that lists the substructure of the TreeView or TreeCell; I did not see much [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#treeview), and there were no related google search results other than the documentation linked. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place? Anyway, I would imagine a second block would go something like below

```
.tree-cell:selected > .hbox
{
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

where `hbox` should be replaced with whatever node contains the icon and label. If anyone could tell me what information I'm missing, or perhaps this is possible an entirely different way? I would really appreciate any efforts.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Near as I can tell, the `TreeCell` itself is the parent of both the graphic and the text. To change that, you could subclass `TreeCell` and put the "graphic" and text in an `HBox`, then set the `HBox` as the graphic of the `TreeCell`. Make the `HBox`'s max size use its preferred size so it doesn't grow to fill the cell. You might also want to add some padding to the `HBox`.

Comment: wondering why you want that? Apart from mimicking the suboptimal UX in older native OS controls ... Anyway, coloring wouldn't be enough, though - you either decide to not allow selection on clicking outside of the text (hard to hit the area for short texts) or have a discrepancy between highlighted and active area

Comment: @Slaw Thank you for the input; valuable as always. I'm attempting to make something like that work currently.

Comment: @kleopatra I want this because I am trying to achieve a very specific appearance and behavior. I am working on a Windows Event Viewer doppelganger with the specific intent of scambaiting (famously done by people like Kitboga). Just as a disclaimer, it is open source and in no way malicious. I haven't made screenshots for the readme yet, as is it a WIP, but you can look at it on github if your interests go that far.

https://github.com/geektechniquestudios/FakeEventViewer

Comment: @kleopatra Also to respond to the other part of your comment, I am maybe probably okay if it allows you to click outside the text area and still select the cell. My goal here is to get a certain appearance, not so much the functionality, as long as it is passable and functional.